# How to convert a BigNumber to a normal number in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, smartcontracts

Guys I am fetching the data from smart contract and it gives a big number in response, I want to convert it into a normal number so that I can use it in order to create a bar chart. How can this be done?
[image]

This is the piece of code I wrote so that I could store the values in an array:

```
//Creating candidatevoterarray for graph
    for (var i =0; i<= 4; i++){
        const temparray = this.candidatearray[i]
        const count = temparray.voteCount
        // this.candidatevotearray.push(count)
        console.log(count)
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

as docs https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/ say there is a method `.toNumber()` in BigNumber

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a `BigNumber` in either [TypeScript](https://typescriptlang.org/) or [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/), nor in [Angular](https://angular.io/). This means that the `BigNumber` must be something you wrote yourself or coming from some library you are not telling us about.

If it is something you wrote yourself, then only you can know how to convert it to a `number` or a `bigint`. If it is something from a library, you will have to look into the documentation of that library.

However, please note that the main reason why someone would write and/or use something like a `BigNumber` class is *because it cannot be represented by `number` or `bigint`* in the first place! So, it may very well be the case that your `BigNumber` *cannot* be converted (accurately) into `number` or `bigint` *at all*.

For example, I just randomly found a library which defines a class / constructor function named `BigNumber` called [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). It has a [`BigNumber.prototype.toNumber` method](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#toN), which converts an instance of `BigNumber` to an ECMAScript primitive `number`. But of course, there are infinitely more `BigNumber`s than there are `number`s (more precisely, there are *countably infinite* `BigNumber`s but only 2<sup>64</sup> `number`s), so this conversion *cannot possibly be* accurate. In particular, there is a smallest and a biggest `number` but there is no smallest or biggest `BigNumber`, so any `BigNumber` bigger than the biggest `number` or smaller than the smallest `number` cannot be represented at all.

Comment: Yes, BigNumber is not actually available right out of the box in TypeScript or any other language in specific. 
It's derived from Ethers.js => https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/

I've managed to 'extract' the 'number' value by using the `then()` method:
```let preCount = await instance.submissionsCount.call().then(v => { return v.toNumber() });
```

Comment: @JÖrgWMittag,a reputation of 355k is huge, so we are a bit scared to reveal that bignumber.js (which provides us with the so called `BigNumber`) is a very popular library among us and we (morons) use it on day-to-day basis to win our breads at the end of the day :)

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this:

```
    const getBalance = async () => {
        try {
            const balance = await token.balanceOf(address)
            console.log(Number(balance._hex))
            return balance;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

        useEffect(() => {
        getBalance().then((res) => setOwnerBalance(Number(res._hex)))    
    }, [data])  

    console.log(Number(balance._hex))
```