# Typescript Convert a Bignumber Array to a normal number TypeError: array.toNumber is not a function

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, ethereum, bignumber.js

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506387/how-to-convert-a-bignumber-to-a-normal-number-in-typescript) here which shows how to convert a BigNumber to a normal number in typescript. The Ethers.jsis typically used for ethereum development and provides a [BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/) type and assists with converting values from onchain to offchain like in javascript applications.

My issue: I have an array called arr composed of BigNumbers that is returned from a function. If I `console.log(arr)` it will be formatted like so:

```js
{
   size: BigNumber { value: '2' },
   pricePerDay: [ BigNumber { value: '103897429' }, BigNumber { value: '103827546' } ],
   unixDate: [ BigNumber { value: '1670268628' }, BigNumber { value: '1670268634' } ]
}
```

Typically to convert a BigNumber to a number the etherjs util you would use the provided `toNumber()` function. So I can convert `size` in the example easily:

```js
arr.size = arr.size.toNumber();
```

But the other numbers within this arr response are `pricePerDay` and `unixDate` which are contained within an array. Is there an easy way to convert the entire array to a regular number?

```js
// this fails with TypeError: arr.priceperDay.toNumber is not a function
arr.pricePerDay = arr.pricePerDay.toNumber()
```

I know I could use map but failed with an overflow error. Heres my attempt to apply the toNumber() function to transform all elements:

```js
// note: i must create a new arr here because the original arr response is read-only
function arrayBigNumberToNumber(arr: BigNumber[] {
    const newArr = arr.map((element: BigNumber, index: number) => {  
        return element.toNumber();
    });
    return newArr;
}

// then I tried to apply the same 
let newArr;
newArr.pricePerDay = arrayBigNumberToNumber(arr.pricePerDay);
newArr.unixDate= arrayBigNumberToNumber(arr.pricePerDay);
```

The above attempt results in the following overflow error:

```
 Error: overflow [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow ] (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber", value="1000000000000000000", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that you provided explains the problem:

```txt
Error: overflow [
  See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow
] (
  fault="overflow",
  operation="toNumber",
  value="1000000000000000000",
  code=NUMERIC_FAULT,
  version=bignumber/5.7.0
)
```

From [the linked documentation](https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow):

> ### Overflow
>
> JavaScript uses [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers to represent numeric values. As a result, there are *holes* in the integer set after 9,007,199,254,740,991; which is problematic for *Ethereum* because that is only around 0.009 ether (in wei), which means any value over that will begin to experience rounding errors.
>
> As a result, any attempt to use a number which is outside the safe range, which would result in incorrect values, an error is thrown.
>
> In general, numbers should be kept as strings, [BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/) instances or using ES2020 bigints, which all can safely be used without loss of precision.

In your case, the value `1000000000000000000` exceeds the maximum integer size for a `number` type in JavaScript, as demonstrated by the following code:

```js
console.log('Max number:', Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log('My number:', '1000000000000000000');

console.log(
  'Is too large?',
  1000000000000000000 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
);
```

and because of that, **the value is not representable as a [`number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#number_type) type in JavaScript**.

In order to work with values of that magnitude, you'll need to use the existing `BigNumber` instances or standard [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) types.

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining. Ill use the `BigNumber` within my backend rather than try to convert them to the `standard` numbers. Answer accepted.